# How to use conditional selection for properties in Altair?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to have a line plot respond to selections on the legend and update some parts of itself accordingly.

Below I have a few failed attempts : (

What I want to achieve is the following: the legend should be split into the available options for 'Country' and 'Mode', as in `chart0`. However, I would like the chart to only plot the data relative to the selected mode(s). I would also like to change Axis labels, scale and other properties when certain options are selected. I think I'm not using `alt.condition()` correctly.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[2,4,3],'bar':[1,2,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[20,30,45],'bar':[50,10,40]})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['foo','bar','foo','bar']])
df.columns = col
df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name=['Mode','Country'], value_name='myvalue').dropna()

country_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Country'], bind='legend')
mode_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Mode'], bind='legend')


chart0 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='index:Q',
    y = alt.Y('myvalue:Q', title='A'),
    color=alt.condition(country_selection, alt.Color('Country:N'), alt.value('lightgray')),
    opacity='Mode:N'
).add_selection(country_selection).add_selection(mode_selection).properties(width=300, height=300)


chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='index:Q',
    y = alt.Y('myvalue:Q', title='A'),
    color=alt.condition(country_selection, alt.Color('Country:N'), alt.value('lightgray')),
).add_selection(country_selection).add_selection(mode_selection).transform_filter(mode_selection).properties(width=300, height=300)



chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='index:Q',
    y = alt.Y('myvalue:Q', title=alt.condition(mode_selection, 'A', 'B')),
    color=alt.condition(country_selection, alt.Color('Country:N'), alt.value('lightgray')),
    opacity='Mode:N'
).add_selection(country_selection).add_selection(mode_selection).transform_filter(mode_selection).properties(width=300, height=300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the selected data to be plotted (with the axis adjusting based on the content of the data), you can use a `transform_filter` to limit the chart to showing the selected data.

In order to have the unselected data appear on the legend, it is important to explicitly set the legend's scale domain:

```py
country_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Country'], bind='legend')
mode_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Mode'], bind='legend')

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='index:Q',
    y = alt.Y('myvalue:Q', title='A'),
    color=alt.Color('Country:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(df.Country.unique()))),
    opacity=alt.Opacity('Mode:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(df.Mode.unique())))
).add_selection(
    country_selection,
    mode_selection
).transform_filter(
    country_selection
).transform_filter(
    mode_selection
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great step ahead for me, thank you! And regarding Y axis label, why doesn't it change when I use a conditional, like in my third example?

Comment: conditions can only be used on encodings, not properties like `title`.

Comment: Do you mean one can use `.encode(x=..., y=alt.condition(a, b, c))`?